# Fiddler not working in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, fiddler

A colleague in work showed me Fiddler the other day.  For the kind of work we do it's really handy.  I decided to install it on my home PC today but for some reason it doesn't seem to work the way I need it to in Chrome.

When I load a page in Chrome nothing happens in Fiddler, but it works fine in IE and FF?  I also seem to be getting a lot of weird stuff like this:
[image: Fiddler]

Any help would be great, I'm well and truly confused!

Thanks :)

**NOTE** - A similar question said to turn off filters?  As far as I can see, they're already off

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fixed this one myself after some playing around.

In Chrome I have an extension called Media Hint which lets me enable/disable it to watch US Netflix from the UK.  This apparently changes my proxy settings, which I suppose makes sense.  But for Fiddler to capture any traffic I guess it looks for the default proxy setting.  So that's what was causing it to not capture anything

And as for the red stuff, not sure what it means or does, but Help > Turn off Troubleshoot Filters gets rid of this!

Hopefully that helps anyone else in my situation :)

Comment: Yes, Chrome Extensions that do not correctly respect the system proxy setting (namely Fiddler) cause it not to send traffic through Fiddler. As explained by the message you saw when you first clicked `Troubleshoot Filters`, that feature unhides all traffic and shows in the Comments column shows why the traffic would have been hidden. `NewOrReusedClosedWithoutRequest` means that a client (in this case, your AVG antivirus proxy `avp.exe`) opened a connection to Fiddler but failed to ever send any HTTP request on it.

Comment: @EricLaw - Is there a way to keep my chrome extensions and still work with fiddler ? Btw, I have a problem with latest fiddler and chrome. Could you please help me to figure out a solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902367/making-fiddler-work-with-chrome

Comment: The same thing goes for `VPN Hola` - Disabled the plugin and voila! Thanks!

Comment: For me it was Tunnel Bear